# How to position text over background image in shopify to work on all screens

Tags: html, css, shopify

I am currently developing a site in shopify using the Timber Framework and have come across some issues in regards to the text size and positioning of the text when the screen size is changed. I have created a new page and written some HTML code and also made a change to page.liquid file.

Unfortunately, whilst the background image will resize to fit the screen size, the text stays the same and some of the margin values that I have used, start to overlap parts of the background image and I am not sure whether I need to write media queries to target different viewports or if theres an easier way to do this.

Currently, the following is an example of the code that I have used:

PAGE

```
<div class="services-page">
<div class="grid__item large">
<div class="grid__item large--one-half service-design-one">
<div class="services-heading red">Heading</div>
<br />
<div class="services-text-large black">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat..</div>
<br />
<div class="services-text-med black">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<br />
<div class="services-sub-heading red">Sub Heading</div>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.page {
  height:6258px;
  width:100%;
}

.services-page {
  background:url({{ bg.jpg' | asset_url }});
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.service-design-one {
  margin:110px 0 800px 0;
  padding: 0 70px 0 30px;
}

.services-heading {
  font-size:2.688em;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.services-sub-heading {
  font-size:30px;
}

.services-sub-heading-med {
  font-size:23px;
}

.services-text-large {
  font-size:30px;
  line-height:1.25;
}

.services-text-med {
  font-size:23px;
  line-height:1.25;
}
```

page.liquid

```
<!-- /templates/page.liquid -->
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid_full">
    {% comment %}
      div class="grid__item large--two-thirds push--large--one-sixth" -- old one
    {% endcomment %}
  <div class="grid__item page"> -- added page to give me height

    {% comment %}
      Regular page content goes here.
    {% endcomment %}

      {{ page.content }}

  </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Any advice or tips to fix this would be really appreciated even if it means starting over.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide some fiddle or codepen example?

Comment: As far as I can see from your code, the text will always overlap the background image. Can you give a link to the image and describe how you want it to overlap? https://jsfiddle.net/yo23vfL3/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses guys. The site can be viewed at https://my-print-store-2.myshopify.com/pages/services but has a password, so not sure if I can message that separately or add it on here and then remove it. You will notice the issues when you resize the window size as the background becomes smaller, the text then overlaps.

Comment: Apologies not sure how I can replicate the code in jsfiddle as part of the code comes from the timber framework.

Comment: sorry eye-wonder, what I would like is when the window resizes, the background image resizes as well and I would like the text to resize as well so that the positioning of the text always remains the same but just reduces in size, whatever size the user is viewing it.